# Quickly get query set of objects related to 2 other objects by a Foreign key

Tags: django, django-orm

Here are my models:

```
class A(models.Model):
  #Some fields

class B(models.Model):
  #Some fields

class C(models.Model):
  a = models.ForeignKey(A)
  b = models.ForeignKey(B)
  #Some more fields

  class Meta:
     unique_together = ['a', 'b']
```

> Now based on some object of A (say 'a') , I want set of all 'b' for which C.a = 'a' and C.b = 'b' .
>   In other words, get a set of objects of B for which entries exist in a.c_set

Currently the way I am doing this is:

```
qset_c = C.objects.filter(a='a')    
qset_b = [c.b for c in qset_c]
```

First of all this gives me a list (a queryset would be preferred).
Second, I am concerned about line 2 having list comprehension , as it may take a lot of time for huge data.

Is there a better way to achieve this?

Note: I understand , the statement is a bit unclear. If someone can edit it to make it more clear, it will be a lot helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this do what you want?

```
set_c = C.objects.filter(a=a).values_list('b', flat=True)
```

Comment: I want to get set_b, i.e a q_set of B, so I wont be able to apply filter b='b'. I edited the question to make this more clear

Comment: Honestly I do not understand what you want.

Comment: And can you avoid to use the word set when you do not mean it - set means something specific in python and is here confusing.

Comment: Changed it to qset

Comment: Basically, given an instance of A (say x), I want  all instances of B for which some C exists, having C.a = x

Comment: Does this make it more clear? If so, I will edit the question

Comment: Woudn't that give this result: C.objects.filter(a=x).values_list('b', flat=True)